# How to set default value of Struts select tag from the Collection

Tags: java, jsp, collections, struts, struts-tags

I am using `<html:select>` tag to read and display values from the collection.

```jsp
<tr>
    <td><bean:message key="prompt.my.amount" /></td>
    <td>
        <html:select property="userPref.amount" style="width:170px">
            <html:options collection="myAmts" property="value" labelProperty="label" />
        </html:select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The Java file contains the collection values.

```java
public Collection getMyAmts() {
    if (Utils.empty(myAmts)) {
        myAmts = new Vector();
        myAmts.add(new LabelValueBean("ONE", "one"));
        myAmts.add(new LabelValueBean("TWO", "two"));
        myAmts.add(new LabelValueBean("Three", "three"));
        myAmts.add(new LabelValueBean("FOUR", "four"));
    }
    return myAmts;
}
```

I would like to display the value `FOUR` as a default in the dropdown list.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why  don't you make it the first one in the collection?

Comment: I am just trying from the above scenario.

Comment: if you set `userPref.amount = "FOUR"` somewhere in your code it should be displayed as selected value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932659/set-default-value-of-select-using-java-in-struts-1-x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value is set in the `value` attribute.

> Have you tried to use the value attribute on the  tag?
>
> ```jsp
> <html:select property="status" value="...your status choise here...">  <html:optionsCollection name="statusList"
> label="description" value="id" /> </html:select>
> ```

**References:**

- [Set default value of select using java in Struts 1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6932659/573032)