# Select option does not show in html

Tags: html, struts

In my struts project I have something like

```
<html:text styleId="textId" name="bean" property="<%=getMyField()%>"/>
<html:select styleId="fieldId" name="bean" property="<%=getMyField()%>"/>
<html:optionsCollection name="bean" property="selectOptions" value="label" label="label" />
```

In html I see something like

```
<select name="myData" id="fieldId">
   <option value="MyFirstValue">MyFirstValue</option>
   <option value="MySecondValue">MySecondValue</option>
   <option value="MyThirdValue">MyThirdValue</option>
</select>
```

There is no selected option and this is correct because from server,for that field I got none full value.  And in browser I see none selected item.

But if I do
document.getElementById('fieldId').childNodes[0].selected
i get true. Why?

Comment: if nothing is marked as selected, the first item will be selected by default

Comment: but how struts understand that nothing selected?

Comment: How can I handle this situation? I have to make some logic on that. When I have nothing selected I do something. I need to do that in JS

Comment: If you want to have a situation where nothing is selected then you need to add an extra option at the top where the value is empty: `<option value="">Please choose</option>` otherwise you will always have a value selected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set default value of Struts select tag from the Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432259/how-to-set-default-value-of-struts-select-tag-from-the-collection)

Comment: Unfortunately, not. Because in that answer was explained, that default value is saved in "value" struts field. But my question is about, How to see/find "FALSE" value of my fieldId with javascript/jquery in rendered page and prepared html